# Display correlation matrix in word document using knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have the .rmd file below which I want to knit and create a word document with the table. The issue is that after knitting I do not get a table but numbers one below the other.

If there is other option Im open to it

````
---
title: "Correlation table"
author: "mk"
date: "17/01/2022"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(scipub)
library(htmlTable)
library(magrittr)
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(666L)
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,include=FALSE}
dat <- as.data.frame(rmvnorm(50, sigma = toeplitz(3:1)))
colnames(dat) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
cortable <- correltable(dat, html = FALSE)
table2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.character(cortable$table), nrow = 3)) 
caption <- cortable[["caption"]]
Means <- formatC(colMeans(dat))
Sds <- formatC(apply(dat, 2L, sd))
table1 <- data.frame(Mean = Means, SD = Sds)
```

```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE}
css.cell <- matrix("padding: 5px;", ncol = 6L, nrow = 4L)
css.cell[, 1L] <- 
  paste(css.cell[, 1L], "font-weight: bold;") # <-- bold row names
cbind(table1, table2) %>%
  addHtmlTableStyle(css.cell = css.cell) %>% 
  htmlTable(caption = caption)
```
````

Comment: Because `htmlTable` doesn't support Word. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542838/formatting-tables-in-r-markdown-to-export-to-ms-word-document

Comment: thank you if you provide as an answer I will accept this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be:

```
---
title: "Correlation table"
author: "mk"
date: "17/01/2022"
output: word_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(scipub)
library(htmlTable)
library(magrittr)
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(666L)
```

```
dat <- as.data.frame(rmvnorm(50, sigma = toeplitz(3:1)))
colnames(dat) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
cortable <- correltable(dat, html = FALSE)
table2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.character(cortable$table), nrow = 3)) 
caption <- cortable[["caption"]]
Means <- formatC(colMeans(dat))
Sds <- formatC(apply(dat, 2L, sd))
table1 <- data.frame(Mean = Means, SD = Sds)
```

```
css.cell <- matrix("padding: 5px;", ncol = 6L, nrow = 4L)
css.cell[, 1L] <- 
  paste(css.cell[, 1L], "font-weight: bold;") # <-- bold row names
cbind(table1, table2) %>%
  addHtmlTableStyle(css.cell = css.cell) %>% 
  htmlTable(caption = caption)
```

```
df <- cbind(table1, table2)
knitr::kable(df)
```

you can play with styles in different ways:

- `kable`: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html
- `flextable`: [How to format kable table when knit from .rmd to Word (with bookdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704329/how-to-format-kable-table-when-knit-from-rmd-to-word-with-bookdown)
- `officeverse` set: https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-word.html#tables

Regards, Grzegorz

Comment: it gives me exactly the same output. does it work for you?

Comment: @firmo23 yes, it does. http://www.sapijaszko.net/up/a.zip

Comment: what is this link?I cant open it

Comment: just zipped files: .Rmd and resulting .docx

Comment: I cant access them please give your full rmd here

Comment: Done. Updated the answer with full code, however it's just two additional lines.